# Ruby Process.daemon: turning on/off

Tags: ruby, daemon, ruby-2.1, ruby-daemons

I am trying to daemonize a Ruby script, running on 2.1.1.

My daemon part of the code is like this:

```
case ARGV[0]
when "-start"
  puts "TweetSearcher started."
  Process.daemon
when "-stop"
  Process.kill(9,Process.pid) 
else
  puts "Lacks arguments. Use -start/-stop"
  abort
end
```

However, it looks like that the `Process.kill(9,Process.pid)` is not killing what I wanted to. I want to kill a previous "`ruby tweetsearcher.rb -start`", already running in background.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the PID is stored in a file that is then read to stop it.

Calling `Process.kill(9,Process.pid)` kills the "stopper" process itself, rather than the one it's trying to stop.

Here's a guide to writing daemons in Ruby: http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2014/9/15/ruby_daemons/

As you can see, it's not a trivial process.

Here is another blog that suggests that you should not try to daemonize at all, but instead rely on a process monitoring system to take care of those concerns: https://www.mikeperham.com/2014/09/22/dont-daemonize-your-daemons/

Comment: It's really a difficult process. Luckly, I was using TweetStream gem and it had a built-in daemon tool.